# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio, noclassdeffounderror

Summary:
When I try loading a DLL and the language in my computer is set to a non-latin based language (such as Korean), I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder`

If you can help me figure out how to avoid this error, I'd appreciate any help.

I am trying to load a Native DLL Library using:

```
Native.loadLibrary
```

But I keep getting these errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.toPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureRandom.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Random.nextLong(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File$TempDirectory.generateFile(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:839)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibraryFromJar(Native.java:751)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:737)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:129)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(RefProp.java:246)
```

I only get this error when I set my language in my computer to Korean (or any other non-Latin language).  When I have it as English, I don't have the error.

By the way, I have set the character encoding as UTF-8:

This code:

```
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
System.out.println("Character Set: " + charset.displayName());
```

Gives this result:

```
Character Set: UTF-8
```

So I know the encoding is not the problem.

I've read through:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

[OSGi noClassDefFound for java.nio.files.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178582/osgi-noclassdeffound-for-java-nio-files-filesystemsdefaultfilesystemholder)
- Doesn't seem to apply because the error is slightly different.

Comment: Please do not refer to `com.sun` nor `sun` packages directly. Use `java.lang.System.loadLibrary` and `java.lang.System.load` instead.

Comment: Are you using java 7 or above?

Comment: @user2656851 Java 7

Comment: @JakubKaszycki Would that change fix the problem that I'm having or are you asking for me not to post it for all to see?

Comment: `com.sun` and `sun` are undocumented, internal, proprietary APIs. For example, Maven even bans calls to such, to prevent importability. I also had some fun once with Sun APIs. But it ended up quickly. One rule - **your API is java, javax and jdk. Do not use sun or com.sun**

Comment: I'm asking because I got this exception few time when I had jar conflicts on runtime.

Comment: And it looks like misconfigured JVM/JRE/JDK

Comment: @JakubKaszycki Ok, I will try that.  I inherited the code and that was already there.  I will work on it and see what happens.  Thanks